# Are complex gaussian integral equivalent to real Gaussian integrals?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I would like to know when it is possible to shift from a gaussian complex integral to a real integral.

For example in the one-variable case it is completely possible:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{C}} e^{-z^{*} z} d z=\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \int_{y \in \mathbb{R}} e^{-\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)} d x d y=\int_{\theta=0}^{2 \pi} \int_{r=0}^{\infty} e^{-r^{2}} r d r d \theta=\pi$$

Is it still possible for integrals of this type?

$$Z= \int e^{-\mathbf{z}^{*} \Gamma^{-1}\mathbf{z}} \; \mathrm{d}\mathbf{z}$$
(Where $\Gamma$ is a Hermitian positive definite matrix)
That would turn into something like this:

$$
I=\int\left(\prod_{k} \mathrm{d} x_{k}\right)\left(\prod_{k} \frac{\mathrm{d} y_{k}}{2\mathrm{i}}\right) \exp \left\{- \sum_{kl} (x_k+\mathrm{i}y_k)  \left( \Gamma^{-1}\right)_{kl}\left(x_l+\mathrm{i}y_l\right) \right\} 
$$

Is $Z=I$? Why?
Is it possible to represent $Z$ as a real integral?

Comment: Why do you divide by $2 i$ in the last integral?

Comment: Sorry, the complex integrals I saw had a $(2\pi\mathrm{i})^{-1}$ prefactor, which I added in my integrals. I could take it out.